# Do warp vote functions synchronize threads in the warp?

Tags: cuda, gpgpu

Do CUDA warp vote functions, such as __*any()* and __*all()*, synchronize threads in the warp?

In other words, is there any guarantee that all threads inside the warp execute instructions preceding warp vote function, especially the instruction(s) that manipulate the predicate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The synchronization is implicit, since threads within a warp execute in lockstep. [*]

Code that relies on this behavior is known as "warp synchronous."

[*] If you are thinking that conditional code will cause threads within a warp to follow different execution paths, you have more to learn about how CUDA hardware works.  Divergent conditional code (i.e. conditional code where the condition is true for some threads but not for others) causes certain threads within the warp to be *disabled* (either by predication or the branch synchronization stack), but each thread still occupies one of the 32 lanes available in the warp.

Comment: For reference: This is outdated for Volta and newer architectures. (The question is too, to be fair, as there are new warp vote functions)

Comment: It isn't, really. All Volta did was augment their existing hardware for predicated execution to enable warps to diverge and give the illusion of threaded execution. If you write code that exhibits full divergence on Volta, it runs 32x slower.

Comment: Well, synchronization isn't implicit anymore and code that relies on that behavior is potentially broken as there is no guarantee that threads in a warp execute in lockstep.

Answer (score 0):

They don't. You can use warp vote functions within code branches. If they would synchronize in such a case there would be a possible deadlock. From the PTX ISA:

> **vote**
>
> Vote across thread group.
>   Syntax

```
 vote.mode.pred  d, {!}a;
 vote.ballot.b32 d, {!}a;  // 'ballot' form, returns bitmask

 .mode = { .all, .any, .uni };
```

> **Description**
>
> Performs a reduction of the source predicate across threads in a warp. The destination > predicate value is the same across all threads in the warp.
>   The reduction modes are:
>
> .all
>       True if source predicate is True for all active threads in warp. Negate the source predicate to compute .none.
>
> .any
>       True if source predicate is True for some active thread in warp. Negate the source predicate to compute .not_all.
>
> .uni
>       True if source predicate has the same value in all active threads in warp. Negating the source predicate also computes .uni.
>
> In the ballot form, vote.ballot.b32 simply copies the predicate from each thread in a warp into the corresponding bit position of destination register d, where the bit position corresponds to the thread's lane id.

**EDIT:**
Since threads within a warp are implicit synchronized you **don't** have to manually ensure that the threads are properly synchronized when the vote takes place. Note that for __all only active threads participate within the vote. Active threads are threads that execute instructions where the condition is true. This explains why a vote can occur within code branches.

Comment: This accepted answer is not accurate.  Synchronization within a warp is implicit.